# Поиск дублей в DataTable

Tags: asp.net, c#

**Добрый день!**

Подскажите, пожалуйста, существуют ли какие-то готовые алгоритмы поиска дублей в DataTable?
Без бесконечных циклов.  В 1С есть такая штука - там в метод поиска передается структура колонок-значений, и на выходе у нас есть новая таблица. Есть ли что-то уже подобное (или не очень), но уже существующее ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [DefaultView.ToTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/wec2b2e6(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
DataTable oldTable = /*исходная таблица*/
DataTable newTable = oldTable.DefaultView.ToTable(true);
```